# How to use container customized volumes from k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume

I am pretty new to kubernetes and docker world. I will try my best to describe my issue as clear as possible.

There is an issue I can't resolve with moving my linux based application to a docker image

My applications is deployed on a linux OS with several mounts, each one have some unique properties. mostly, specific file system type (`tmpfs`, `ext4` or `xfs`), `mode`, `nr_inodes` and so on. Those properties can be seen as they appear in `mount` output.

In docker, this is possible to create such volumes using `docker volume create ...` and then mounting those volumes on specific paths when `docker run`. Most of these volume's lifespan should end with the container itself.

In k8s, I can't find a way to the same level of details. `tmpfs` file systems are available. But it isn't clear what additional properties can be mentioned such as requested/limited size. Plus I am pretty sure the volumes requested are for POD level and can not be directly assigned to containers.
Alternative approach might be using the docker volumes, as mentioned above. However it isn't clear to me how to initialize them and use them as part of the pod life cycle, if possible.

I look over the the kubernetes storage pages and couldn't find something that might help.

Any insight using out-of-tree plugins for this purpose? Do I miss out kubernetes features that allow it?

Other useful information:

1. Currently the solution assumes 1xcontainer for 1xpod.
2. All Worker nodes are same machines and provide them same file system storage drivers and same hardware
3. Kubernetes version: 1.18.6

Comment: Container environments tend to hide details of the underlying filesystem like this.  In Kubernetes in particular, the assumption is that a pod can run anywhere in the cluster, which doesn't match well with detailed filesystem configuration on physical disks.  Why do you need these very specific filesystem options?

Comment: @DavidMaze in my case perhaps most the specifications can be discarded, but I still need to allocate RAM drives per CONTAINER and limit their maximum size. Also all nodes are similar by hw spec. I know I can define tmpfs in deployment.yaml, but I can't cap the maximum size of it

Generally I assume if some mount points have intensive I/O work, those very specific filesystems optimizations will be needed.